# Test class running through an if statement

Tags: query, database

I have the following code in one of my batches:

```
if (exclusionsize == 1){
        exclusion1 = exclusioncut[0];
        System.debug('Preforming the Query: ' + 'select ' + TrackingNumberString + ',Carrier_Status__c from ' 
                                        + MainObjectString + ' where ECS__Shipped_Time__c = LAST_N_DAYS:' 
                                        + DaysBackString + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion1) + '\'');
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select ' + TrackingNumberString + ',Carrier_Status__c from ' 
                                        + MainObjectString + ' where ECS__Shipped_Time__c = LAST_N_DAYS:' 
                                        + DaysBackString + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion1) + '\'');
    } else if (exclusionsize == 2){
        exclusion1 = exclusioncut[0];
        exclusion2 = exclusioncut[1];
        System.debug('Preforming the Query: ' + 'select ' + TrackingNumberString + ',Carrier_Status__c from ' 
                                        + MainObjectString + ' where ECS__Shipped_Time__c = LAST_N_DAYS:' 
                                        + DaysBackString + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion1) + '\'' +  
                                        + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion2) + '\'');
        return Database.getQueryLocator('select ' + TrackingNumberString + ',Carrier_Status__c from ' 
                                        + MainObjectString + ' where ECS__Shipped_Time__c = LAST_N_DAYS:' 
                                        + DaysBackString + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion1) + '\'' +  
                                        + ' and Carrier_Status__c != ' + '\'' + String.escapeSingleQuotes(exclusion2) + '\'');
```

Where all of the variables work, etc...

However exclusionsize is based on a custom setting, and when I am testing this class I can only have one entry for that custom setting (so exclusion size can only be either 2 or 1 depending on my setting).

Therefore, when I test the class, it goes through ignoring exclusionsize == 1 if it equals 2.  So my test results in a very low percentage.

Is there any way I can get all of the if responses to run in a test?

Comment: Just update the custom setting to be 1 during the first test methods. Make another test method setting the value to 2

Comment: this calls out for using NOT IN operator and thus avoiding the whole duplicated dyn SOQL

Answer (score 5):

You can create / update custom settings during a test method...

Structure it as such (pseudo code as I do not know the name or type of your custom setting)

```
private static test method void exclusion1(){
    exclusionsSetting__c exc = exclusionsSetting__c.getOrgDefaults( userinfo.getOrganizationID())); //Assuming it is not a list type
    exc.exclusions__c = 1;
    upsert exc;

    ....do test stuff....
}

private static test method void exclusion1(){
    exclusionsSetting__c exc = exclusionsSetting__c.getOrgDefaults( userinfo.getOrganizationID())); //Assuming it is not a list type
    exc.exclusions__c = 2;
    upsert exc;

    ....do test stuff....
}
```